# WSO2 mapping email to user via ldap

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting to add google as an identity provider to wso2.  I have
it configured to the point where wso2 send me to google for
authentication and google returns an email address.  wso2 is then trying
to use the email address as the username.  It is using the following
ldap filter query:

```
    (&(objectClass=account)(uid=myemail@domain.edu))
```

When it should be using something like:

```
    (&(objectClass=account)(mail=myemail@domain.edu))
```

How do I affect this change in wso2?

Comment: Did you enable email login?

Comment: Yes, we had that enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit repository/conf/user-mgmt.xml and fine the line:

```
(&(objectClass=account)(uid=?))
```

and modify it to:

```
(&(objectClass=account)(|(uid=?)(mail=?)))
```

This allows it to find the ldap entry if it is passed a username or an email address.